How to add a horizontal scrollbar in Angular / Html / CSS
I am currently working on project where I want to implement a horizontal scrollbar above a normal one
I managed to actually do it with this (horizontal one - vertikal one works fine):
HTML
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
</div>[[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/pECzlvfg.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/7AB0cpRe.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/itT59I8j.png)

CSS
.wrapper
{
    max-height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid aqua;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    
}

.wrapper .item
{
min-width: 110px;
height: 110px;
line-height: 110px;
background-color: blue;
margin-right: 1px;
}

But my issue now is that I cant manage to let it look like the vertikal items
This is my code vor the vertikal items:
HTML
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let p of plants">
        <a routerLink="/detail/{{p.id}}"></a>
        <img [src]="p.imageUrl[0]">
        <div class="content">
        <div class="name">
            {{p.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="rating">
            <span class="star">⋆</span> {{p.rating}}
        </div>
        <div class="detail">
            {{p.price | currency}}
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>

CSS
ul
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0;
}

li a
{
    height: 12.5rem;
    width: 10rem;
    border: 1px solid violet;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: darkolivegreen;
}

li a:hover
{
    opacity: 0.9;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li a img
{
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 14.5rem;
}

.content
{
    margin-top: 0.3rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    padding: 0.5r 1rem;
    position: relative;
    height: 7rem;
    background-color: aqua;
}

When I try to just copy this the code for my vertikal scrollbar it looks weird and the items are aligned underneath instead of next to each other

Please try to this code
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="item" *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="onItemClick(item)">
    <img [src]="item.imageUrl" alt="Item image">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="name">{{ item.name }}</div>
        <div class="rating">{{ item.rating }}</div>
        <div class="detail">{{ item.price | currency }}</div>
    </div>
</div>

CSS Add :-
.wrapper {
display: flex;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;  
white-space: nowrap; 
border: 1px solid aqua; 
padding: 0.5rem; 
margin: 0.5rem; 
}

.wrapper .item {
    min-width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    line-height: 110px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-right: 1px;
    border-radius: 1rem; 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;     
    align-items: center; 
    color: darkolivegreen; 
    cursor: pointer; 
}

.wrapper .item:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
}


PLease try to my code apply. If changes problem, then let me know!
